# Trouble retrieving contacts already on the app from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm looking to do something similar to most popular apps (e.g. Snapchat) where users verify their phone numbers, then give the app permission to their Contacts so friends who have already signed up can be displayed.

I'd like two table view sections. One section for contacts NOT on the app, and another section for contacts whose phone numbers matched one in the Parse column, "phoneNumber". The second section is causing this error telling me I'm running multiple queries at once.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.'

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
let query = PFUser.query()

    for person in self.people! { // iterate through phone contacts
        let numbers = person.phoneNumbers
        let primaryNumber = numbers?.map({$0.value})[0] // pull contact's first phone number (i.e. main number)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        query?.whereKey("phoneNumber", equalTo: primaryNumber!)
        query?.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in

            self.contactsOnTheApp.addObject(object!) // create array of users already on the app to then show in table view section
        })
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `query` outside the loop and then perform a background query inside the loop. You modify the existing query on each loop iteration  but as the first  background query hasn't completed when you modify the query for the next search you get the error message.

You can move the `let query=PFUser.query()` inside the for loop but it would be more efficient to create an array of phone numbers and use a `containedIn` condition on a single query and then loop through the returned results.

Also you don't need the `dispatch_async` since you are using the background Parse call and you don't need to dispatch the reload on the main queue. In fact, you are executing the reload too early because your queries won't be complete. You need to reload from the query completion block. This will be easier if you have a single query too.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That worked but I'm struggling with the query using containedIn. I have an array of all the phone numbers in the Address Book, but my query doesn't seem to pick up matching phone numbers in Parse. Here is what the query looks like:

`let query = PFUser.query()
        query?.whereKey("phoneNumber", containedIn: myContactsPhoneNumbers as [AnyObject])
        query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
            
            for existingUser in objects! {
                self.contactsOnApp.append(existingUser)
            }
            
      })`